# How to add OJDBC6.jar in build.gradle file?

Tags: java, gradle, build, ojdbc

I am connecting to Oracle Db in my application and trying to build the app with gradle build.
I am unable to access the OJDBC6.jar from gradle build.
can some one please, let me know that, how can we add the ojdbc6.jar into the build.gradle file.

Comment: If possible you should use a binary repository like Artifactory or Nexus to pull this jar from.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to load your OJDBC dependency as a runtime requirement as follows:

```
dependencies {
    runtime files('path/to/OJDBC6.jar')
}
```