# oracle 11g ojdbc6.jar MissingMethodException

Tags: oracle, groovy, oracle11g, cuba-platform

I have a cuba app which uses a oracle db and groovy. I've put the driver jar in build/tomcat/lib folder. I don't use the db creation mechanism of the platform, because I don't have the system user. If I "create" the db I drop the database tables manually. Therefor the starting point is a empty oracle db/schema. If I want to update the db a get this exception:

```
Task 'updateDb' failed
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method:
java.util.ArrayList.call() is applicable for argument types:
(org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values:
[/home/SVN/trunk/apps/some-app/build/tomcat/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
Possible solutions: tail(), tail(), wait(), any(), last(), last()
```

I already tried to move the `def oracle = files("$cuba.tomcat.dir/lib/ojdbc6.jar")` entry in build.gradle up and down. But nothing changed. I can imagine that the problem appears by using groovy and the oracle-driver.

Comment: You've declared a variable called `files` so you've lost whatever your method was

Comment: Please try to execute from the command line in the project's directory: gradle updateDb --stacktrace. Then post the output here. Also provide the platform and Gradle version.

Comment: You have not shown how `def oracle` is used later on. Maybe this answer point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246214/how-to-add-ojdbc6-jar-in-build-gradle-file#33248711